# how to verify email through link in rails4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

How to verify email through link.

I have user edit profile and it is showing user email.I want to give one link to verify email.I do not what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add one column to your

> User Model : email_verification  and by default set to zero (0).

Then using persistence_token create a URL and sent to that specific email address. If you dnt have persistence_token as column in your User model then you can add custom column of your choice like verify_email_token as column name and stored 50 random string.

Using

```
o =  [('a'..'z'),('A'..'Z'),('0'..'9')].map{|i| i.to_a}.flatten
string  =  (0...50).map{ o[rand(o.length)] }.join
```

> URL example :
>   http://www.yoursitename.com/VerifyEmailAddress/?token=persistence_token ;

When user click on that link, internally call function like `VerifyEmailAddress` and in that method update email_verification column by one (1).